# Applescript to copy each file/folder into new created folder

Tags: applescript

I have an Applescript to copy files from one directory to another destination automatically. As I am new in Apple Script and I am facing issue while copying file/folder into newly created folder.

## As my script is like this

```
set dt to (current date) as Unicode text 

tell application "Finder"
  make new folder at alias "Macintosh HD:Users:XYZ:" with properties {name:dt}
  //In above code, new folder create automatically with system date and time on specified location like Tuesday, October 1, 2015 at 12/02/48 PM
  copy folder "Macintosh HD:Users:XYZ:Desktop:ABC:" to folder "Macintosh HD:Users:XYZ:"
  //In above code, I am facing issue that I am not able to copy file into created newly system date and time folder. How can I copy folder into newly created system date and time folder?
end tell
```

Can any one please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the Finder command to copy items is `duplicate`.

`make new folder` returns a reference to the new folder. Use this reference as destination.

```
set dt to (current date) as Unicode text 

tell application "Finder"
  set newFolder to make new folder at alias "Macintosh HD:Users:XYZ:" with properties {name:dt}
  duplicate folder "Macintosh HD:Users:XYZ:Desktop:ABC:" to newFolder
end tell
```

Comment: You was first, I delete my identical answer :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. **Vadian** You have solved my issue. Thanks a lot once again. :)